# How to get the number (count) of selected checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have following code

```
<ul class="myfilterside  catfilter">
<li>
    <input type="checkbox"  value="1" class="filter" name="Bedroom">
    <a id="1" href="javascript:void(0)" class="filter1"> test1 </a>
</li>

<li>
    <input type="checkbox"  value="2" class="filter" name="Corridor">
    <a id="2" href="javascript:void(0)" class="filter1"> test2 </a>
</li>

<li>
    <input type="checkbox"  value="3" class="filter" name="Test">
    <a id="3" href="javascript:void(0)" class="filter1"> test3 </a>
</li>

</ul>
<input type="button" value="Clear All" class="check">
<script>
jQuery('.check:button').click(function(){ 
            jQuery('.filter').removeAttr('checked');                    
            jQuery(this).val('Clear All');              
        }); 
</script>
```

On clicking the button I want to get the count of all selected checkboxes. That means if two checkboxes are checked the I want to get the count =2
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[:checked](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)** selector to get the checked checkboxes and `length` to get the total number of these checkboxes:

```
var length = $('.filter:checkbox:checked').length;
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QU8S7/)**

Answer (score 5):

You can use `:checked` to get selected checkboxes

```
var checked = $('.filter:checked').length;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$(".filter:checked").length
```

Refer this [link](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) for more details about `:checked` selector

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
jQuery('.count:button').click(function(){ 
    var count =0;
    $("input.filter:checkbox").each(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked') ){
            count++;   
        }
    });
    alert(count);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4sKtS/)